# Suppressing Gradle warnings caused by Apache POI

Tags: gradle, apache-poi

Using the Apache POI library via Gradle causes the following warning:

> Class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTPhoneticRun not found - continuing with a stub.

Google suggests this isn't really an issue: https://github.com/norbert-radyk/spoiwo/issues/22 . But, how do I suppress this warning?

My `build.gradle` contains

```
        'org.apache.poi:poi:3.11',
        'org.apache.poi:poi-examples:3.11',
        'org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml:3.11',
        'org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml-schemas:3.11'
```

NB. I don't want to include an extra library and bloat the filesize unnecessarily. Suppressing the warning at compile-time is fine.

Thanks!

Comment: Use a newer version of Apache POI? 3.11 is a bit old now!

Comment: @Gagravarr: 3.17 doesn't fix it.

Answer (score 0):

You can likely stop this warning via [CompileOptions.warnings](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.compile.CompileOptions.html#org.gradle.api.tasks.compile.CompileOptions:warnings) eg:

```
apply plugin: 'java'

dependencies { ... }

compileJava {
    options.warnings = false
}
```

Comment: Is there any way of suppressing that specific warning (or '... is a stub') without suppressing all warnings, which could hide something important?